# Entity Framework EF6 Add data to Many to Many relationship Table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a many to many relationship that will allow me to add multiple complaints and employees to a table. I am fairly new to EF.

this is going to be simpler that what I already have but it will help anwser my question:

**Employee:**

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

}
```

**Complaint:**

```
   public class Complaint
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; } 
    }
```

**ComplaintXEmployee:**

```
public class ComplaintXEmployee
{
    public ComplaintXEmployee()
    {
        Employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
        Complaints = new HashSet<Complaint>();
    }

    public int ComplaintXEmployeeId { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public int ComplaintId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Complaint> Complaints { get; set; } 
}
```

**Main**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var complaintList = new List<Complaint>()
        {
            new Complaint() {Description = "This is a Test"}
        };

        var employeeList = new List<Employee>()
        {
            new Employee() {FirstName = "John", Id = 1, LastName = "Doe"},
            new Employee() {FirstName = "Jane", Id = 2, LastName = "Doe"},
            new Employee() {FirstName = "Kid", Id = 3, LastName = "Smith"}
        };

        var c = new ComplaintXEmployee();

        //from here I dont know

        using (var context = new FakeEntities())
        {
            context.ComplaintXEmployees.Add(c);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

How do I add both lists to ComplaintXEmployees?

Comment: Dont know what exactly!

Comment: sorry didn't add the question in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is add the navigation properties to your entities. (I've added some extra attributes just for fun)

```
[Table("Employee")] //can be Employees
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLenth(64)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [StringLenth(64)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Complaint> Complaints { get; set; } 
}    

[Table("Complaint")] //can be Complaints
public class Complaint
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLenth(128)]
    public string Description { get; set; } 

    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

To manually define the intermediate table - in your DbContext you can use FluentApi like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
            .Entity<Employee>()
            .HasMany(fa => fa.Complaints)
            .WithMany(u => u.Employees)
            .Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("EmployeeId")
                 .MapRightKey("ComplaintId")
                 .ToTable("ComplaintXEmployee"));
}
```

Attributes

[Key] tells entity framework that it must use this "column" as the primary key for the table.

[StringLenth(128)] tells entity framework that the column length is 128. It's always better to specify the length, otherwise entity framework will assume its a NVARCHAR(MAX).

[Table("Employee")] tells entity framework the table name you want to use. If you leave this out, it will use the plural form of the class name.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Can you explain why I need the attributes?

Comment: Updated my answer to explain what the attributes do.

Answer (score 0):

You don`t need to manually add many-to-many table because EF will do it for you:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Complaint> Complaints { get; set; } 
}    

public class Complaint
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; } 

    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

This class declarations will generate table automatically.
Adding relationship between entities is trivial:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var context = new FakeEntities())
    {
        var complaintList = new List<Complaint>()
        {
            new Complaint() {Description = "This is a Test"}
        };
        Context.Complaint.AddRange(complaintList);

        var employeeList = new List<Employee>()
        {
            new Employee() {FirstName = "John", Id = 1, LastName = "Doe"},
            new Employee() {FirstName = "Jane", Id = 2, LastName = "Doe"},
            new Employee() {FirstName = "Kid", Id = 3, LastName = "Smith"}
        };
        Context.Employee.AddRange(employeeList);

        //Just add entities to corresponding collections.
        employeeList[0].Complaints.Add(complaintList[0]);

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Weird you were like 99% of the way there.

Is it because you didn't declare any keys and relationships...
 if so then the other answer by Sean Thorburn is better!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var complaintList = new List<Complaint>()
    {
        new Complaint() {Description = "This is a Test"}
    };

    var employeeList = new List<Employee>()
    {
        new Employee() {FirstName = "John", Id = 1, LastName = "Doe"},
        new Employee() {FirstName = "Jane", Id = 2, LastName = "Doe"},
        new Employee() {FirstName = "Kid", Id = 3, LastName = "Smith"}
    };

    var c = new ComplaintXEmployee();
    c.Employees = employeeList;
    c.Complaints = complaintList;

    using (var context = new FakeEntities())
    {
        context.ComplaintXEmployees.Add(c);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```